# C# Buttons not repositioning themselves

Tags: c#, .net, button, panel

I have included 4 buttons inside a panel. The panel is docked to the main window.

When I resize the main window, it doesn't reposition the 4 buttons with respect to the newly modified window size. I am using VS 2010 Designer view to accomplish this.

Here is the entire code generated from designer.cs

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.statusStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel();
    this.TreeDDC = new System.Windows.Forms.TreeView();
    this.BtnPointCtrl = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.BtnLogic = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.BtnComm = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.BtnSystem = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
    this.statusStrip1.SuspendLayout();
    this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // statusStrip1
    // 
    this.statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1});
    this.statusStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 445);
    this.statusStrip1.Name = "statusStrip1";
    this.statusStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(639, 22);
    this.statusStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.statusStrip1.Text = "statusBar";
    // 
    // toolStripStatusLabel1
    // 
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel1";
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 17);
    this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status Bar";
    // 
    // TreeDDC
    // 
    this.TreeDDC.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
    this.TreeDDC.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.TreeDDC.Name = "TreeDDC";
    this.TreeDDC.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 445);
    this.TreeDDC.TabIndex = 1;
    // 
    // BtnPointCtrl
    // 
    this.BtnPointCtrl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 93);
    this.BtnPointCtrl.Name = "BtnPointCtrl";
    this.BtnPointCtrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(202, 86);
    this.BtnPointCtrl.TabIndex = 2;
    this.BtnPointCtrl.Text = "???";
    this.BtnPointCtrl.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // BtnLogic
    // 
    this.BtnLogic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 282);
    this.BtnLogic.Name = "BtnLogic";
    this.BtnLogic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(202, 86);
    this.BtnLogic.TabIndex = 4;
    this.BtnLogic.Text = "??";
    this.BtnLogic.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // BtnComm
    // 
    this.BtnComm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(307, 93);
    this.BtnComm.Name = "BtnComm";
    this.BtnComm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(202, 86);
    this.BtnComm.TabIndex = 3;
    this.BtnComm.Text = "??";
    this.BtnComm.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // BtnSystem
    // 
    this.BtnSystem.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(307, 282);
    this.BtnSystem.Name = "BtnSystem";
    this.BtnSystem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(202, 86);
    this.BtnSystem.TabIndex = 5;
    this.BtnSystem.Text = "???";
    this.BtnSystem.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // panel1
    // 
    this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnSystem);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnComm);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnPointCtrl);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnLogic);
    this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(97, 0);
    this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
    this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(542, 445);
    this.panel1.TabIndex = 6;
    // 
    // MainForm
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 12F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(639, 467);
    this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
    this.Controls.Add(this.TreeDDC);
    this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
    this.Name = "MainForm";
    this.Text = "MainForm";
    this.statusStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.statusStrip1.PerformLayout();
    this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();

}
```

But I believe the only code of interest will be the following:

```
this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;


this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnSystem);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnComm);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnPointCtrl);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnLogic);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mark at least one answer as accepted... If issue resolved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property of the buttons...

Read it [Working with Anchoring and Docking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2231/Working-with-Anchoring-and-Docking-Properties)

The Panel does not itself repositioning the controls when it resizing, Use the `Anchor (Top, Bottom, Left, Right)` property that the controls reposition when parent Panel resizes...

Or Use [TableLayOutPanel](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/tablelayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/).

Answer (score 3):

Docking the panel will only resize the panel iteelf, not reposition the controls within the panel. To have elements within a container change their position after resizing the container, look into the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property. There is also [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) which can, as its name suggests, layout controls in a table format.

Answer (score 0):

Please Dock a FlowLayoutPanel inside your panel and palce the buttons inside that FlowLayoutPanel. Set the Layout Direction property. Now when you resize the main window your buttons will also be resized.